# DNN Jwt Authorization request not working from from C# Desktop Application

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, jwt, dotnetnuke

I have Web API REST service running, I can authroize using Jwt from ajax requests but I cannot do the same with http requests from the C# desktop application, I am trying to set the Authorization but I always get UnAuthorized 401 error:
here is one piece of code I tried: where accessToken is the token I get when after login successfully.

```
         using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var url = "SERICE ADDRESS";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            var response = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
        }
```

Can you please help what is missing to get the authorization working from desktop application.

Comment: Can you debug into your Web API and see where the authorization is being rejected? BTW, two serious flaws are creating a new HttpClient for each request instead of sharing one instance, and blocking on async calls with `.Result`.

Comment: I cannot debug the authorization method because it is part of DNN CMS 
never mind other code issues for now ,this is sample code to authorize

Comment: I would trace the http calls with browser dev tools while doing the ajax operations so you can see everything that is going into the request.

Comment: like I said the ajax calls works well from browser and authrorize without a problem, only problem with c# app

Comment: I know, that's why I would look at the http traffic that is working so I could craft the c# code to do the same thing.

Comment: I have added some headers from the browser dev tools to c# but still 401 error

Comment: You might want to tag the question with DNN. As is there is not enough info to answer but maybe someone has already done the same thing with DNN.

Comment: ok thank you will do that

Comment: sorry my bad the web config settings were set to force SSL somehow this was passing with ajax

Answer (score 2):

sorry, It was something else the web.config for messageHandlers>JWTAuth 
forceSSL was set to true.
Somehow this was not failing with ajax non SSL calls, but it was failing with C# calls setting this to false solved the problem.